# Unable to display the express res.send() custom error message on the vue side

Tags: mysql, express, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt app with express and mySQL.

**Problem** : I am unable to display the express res.send() custom error message on the vue side

Let's pretend I want to display infos of one single user.

Here is my back-end code :

```
// Find a single User with a userId
exports.findOne = (req, res) => {
  User.findById(req.params.userId, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      if (err.kind === 'not_found') {
        res.status(404).send({
          message: `Not found User with id ${req.params.userId}.`
        })
      } else {
        res.status(500).send({
          message: 'Error retrieving User with id ' + req.params.userId
        })
      }
    } else { res.send(data) }
  })
}
```

And here is the Vue part

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import appNavbar from '~/components/appNavbar.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    appNavbar
  },
  data () {
    return {
      userId: '',
      userData: '',
      errorMsg: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetchUser (evt) {
      evt.preventDefault()
      return axios.get('/api/users/' + this.userId)
        .then((res) => {
          this.userData = res.data
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          this.errorMsg = err.toJSON()
        })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

When I give the id of a non-existing user, I want to be able to get the custom error message written in the back, and display it in the front

BUT I only get this JSON

```
{ "message": "Request failed with status code 404", "name": "Error" }
```

Does anyone have a clue ?
Thanks !

Comment: I would try to isolate more the problem. As it is a GET method request, you can easily test it with any browser. In a browser, try going to the address: 'http://[endpoint]/api/users/[wrong-id]'. What is the result? If you see the correct result, then it's probably something inside the axios (I don't know this lib). If you see the wrong result, then try to ensure that the code is really entering the `(err.kind === 'not_found')` IF, maybe putting some logging over there....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT : SOLUTION FOUND**

Answer found here: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/960#issuecomment-309287911

On the vue part, the catch should return `err.response`, and not just `err`.
So in order to display your custom error message, it should be like this:

```
.catch((err) => {
          this.errorMsg = err.response
```

---

Answer (score 0):

This error maybe occours because you are not setting the host when you call teh API at line:

`return axios.get('/api/users/' + this.userId)`

404 error is because browser not found this endpoint.
In this case, I recommend you try to call this endpoint in another tool (like Postman) and certify if your API is responding correctly.
After that, fix your call to endpoint, maybe it will be somwthing like the code bellow and try again:

```
return axios.get(`${your host here}/api/users/ + ${this.userId}`)
```